# std::bad_alloc trouble with QPixmap()

Tags: c++, qt

I am attempting a build of one of our GUI projects. This build works on every machine in the office save the two new machines. Here is the terminal output of the error:

```
viewPriorityChanged( 11, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 12, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 13, 0 )
MainWindow.cpp debug print #5
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
./runlp_common: line 320: 11123 Aborted  (core dumped) $3
```

As you can see I have traced it down in the code with print statements. Here is the method that is erring in the code:

```
void MainWindow::updateDecoration()
{
  Geometry::DisplayTypes closest = Geometry::closestDisplayType();
  QString closestStr = Geometry::displayTypeString(closest).toLower();
  QString iconPath  = QString(QLatin1String(":/images/device_skin_%1.png")).
                              arg(closestStr);

  Messages::conout() << "MainWindow.cpp debug print #5" << std::endl;

  m_device = QPixmap(iconPath); <-- not making it past here

  Messages::conout() << "MainWindow.cpp debug print #6" << std::endl;

  QBitmap clBitmap = m_device.createHeuristicMask();
  setFixedSize(m_device.size());
  setMask(clBitmap);
  update();
}
```

It is the strangest thing (in my opinion) that this line would be causing just a few machines trouble. Any ideas what could be going on here?

EDIT:

I wanted to give a more detailed description of the terminal output:

```
MainWindow.cpp debug print #1
MainWindow.cpp debug print #2
ToolsViewConfigTip_Series: Preloading tip images
ToolsViewConfigTip_Capacity: Preloading tip images.
ln: cannot remove '/etc/localtime': Permission denied
Using QGLBridge
Using QGLBridge
QThread::start: Thread creation error: Resource temporarily unavailable
libpng error: Read Error
libpng error: Read Error
libpng error: Read Error
libpng error: Read Error
libpng error: Read Error
libpng error: Read Error
libpng error: Read Error
libpng error: Read Error
QImage::scaled: Image is a null image
viewPriorityChanged( 0, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 1, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 2, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 3, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 4, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 5, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 6, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 7, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 10, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 11, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 12, 0 )
viewPriorityChanged( 13, 0 )
MainWindow.cpp debug print #4
MainWindow.cpp debug print #5
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
./runlp_common: line 320: 22676 Aborted                 (core dumped) $3
----------- KillAllApps -----------
IsobusMuxServer::clientDisconnected() Client 1 is now disconnected and destroyed
IsobusMuxServer::clientDisconnected() Client 0 is now disconnected and destroyed
-----------------------------------
```

I took the suggestion about using valgrind in the comments. Prior to this point in the program there actually are no alllocs, frees and no bytes are allocated. I tried running the other various tools in the valgrind package without any luck. The only other error I get is when running helgrind:

```
ProprietarySocketServer::startServer() bind: Address already in use
ProprietarySocketServer::startServer() Could not bind on port 41263
```

Comment: `what():  std::bad_alloc` -- 1) Running out of heap memory or  2) An allocation function was given a wild (maybe negative) number of bytes to allocate.  What does the call stack say?

Comment: Instead of using copy assignment `m_device = QPixmap(iconPath);` have you tried to use load? `m_device.load(iconPath);`? Copy assignment could potentially allocate more memory. Also make sure the file you are loading actually exists, is a reasonable size and is valid image.

Comment: One other possibility (in addition to the ones mentioned in the comments above) is that some buggy code that ran earlier in your program corrupted the heap in such a way that the heap allocator only "noticed" the corruption when the QPixmap constructor tried to allocate memory.  If that's the case, it can be tough to track down, since the problem could be anywhere from the top of main() onwards.  You can probably find it by moving your calls to updateDecoration() to various places in the program until you find the boundary between crash and no-crash (or on Linux, try valgrind to find the bug)

Comment: @Tony J I tried what you suggested to no avail unfortunately, thanks though.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner I tried using valgrind as you suggested. I have made an EDIT to my original post with regards to that, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Note the libpng failures. They are what most likely leads to `QPixmap`'s code attempting to do some funny allocation.

Comment: With the libpng errors and not working on only two machines, I would suggest to check the libpng version see if there is any difference.

Comment: @Tony J Along those same lines. The other machines capable of building are using an older version of gcc. Specifically, the other machines are using gcc98 whereas these two new machines are using gcc11. An attempt at trying to force Qt to compile with gcc98 was made but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Tony J What would I be check the version of libpng against?